Python watch-dog module: Is there a way to raise an event when nothing happens after a while?
Is there a way to raise an event when nothing happens after a while? I mean, I have a log which is updated from second to second, but I'd like to do something when this log not will be updated for a while. I have had a glance to the different parameters of the watchdog module, but I haven't find the correct way to do that.
Any idea?
Thanks.
I'm trying to find a function from watch-dog module to allow me doing something if nothing happens after a while.

"Watchdog" was a reasonable search term, but this module is implementing an entirely different definition of that word than what you need.  You could perhaps use threading.Timer, from the standard library - every time you see an event, call .cancel() on the existing Timer, and start a new one.
